# MVC Model property resets on page submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC so this may sound silly, but here goes: I have a model that contains two lists that need to be passed to an edit form:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<portal_notifications_types> Types { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<portal_notifications_importances> Importances { get; set; }
}
```

In the edit form, i Have two dropdownlists for this fields:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Notification.TypeId, new SelectList(Model.Types, "Id", "Type"), "-- Select type --", new { onchange = "GetNotifType();", style = "width:150px;" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Notification.ImportanceId,  new SelectList(Model.Importances, "Id", "Importance"), "-- Select importance --", new { style = "width:150px;" })
```

When I first enter the edit view, everything is ok, the dropdownlists are populated and the corresponding value is selected.
 However, when I submit the form, the dropdownlists throw an error, because the Model.Types and Model.Importances lists are null.
 How could I overcome this ? I would like to avoid using ViewBag to store those lists, although I know it would work.

Comment: I don't see anything called Notification in your Model.  Given that it says "BaseViewModel" I assume this is not your actual model, but a parent class of your model.  You need to include both your controller action method and your actual model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the *View Model* again in your `Post` *Action Method*.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel m)
{
     return View(m); //Pass the View Model again.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to repopulate these two `SelectLists` in the `Controller` `POST` method for `Edit` and again pass the `ViewModel` in the view for edit. Please share your `Controller` code for `Edit` for more details.